# semantic-ui modal stretching window height

Tags: jquery, css, semantic-ui

I see on this page: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#/examples

That to avoid this you can simple add the 'long' class to the modal. I did this but it still is stretching the window height. Does anyone have any ideas why this would be, or how I can debug this behavior? I want to be able to scroll my modal, without having it stretch the window height.

Comment: Please show us your code, so we can help

Comment: The example does not stretch the parent window height. It only adjusts the modal's dimmer to enable scrolling within the dimmer div.

Comment: My code is too complex to post in a snippet I'm afraid. But I noticed something weird. When I remove the content in the long modal, and replace with a div of fixed height=3000px, the scrolling works. But if I then place my content inside that div, the modal stretches my window height. Any ideas on that behavior?

Comment: Now I'm fully stumped. I mirrored my setup in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mikestaub/waxLrqk8/ But when I uncomment lines 13-15 in my own code, the red section increases by 3k pixel after scrolling. Do semantic modals not play well with angular ng-repeat?

Comment: Related / dup: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30342059/2302269

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this in the future, the workaround that I ended up using was just to add this css rule:

```
body{ max-height: 100vh; }
```

Answer (score 3):

this is possible

http://jsfiddle.net/MrLogical/2hda8e18/

```js
$('.modal-btn').click(function(){
    $('.modal-content').show();
});
$('.modal-btn-close').click(function(){
    $('.modal-content').hide();
});
```

```css
.modal-btn{color:red; cursor:pointer;}

.modal-content{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    display:none;
    position:fixed; 
    top:0px; left:0px;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.modal-content div{ background-color:#FFF; box-shadow:0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); border-radius:20px; padding:20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Run This Code <span class="modal-btn">Click Me !!!</span>

<div class="modal-content">
    <div style="margin:30px; min-height:1000px;">
        Long Content
        <hr/>
        <span class="modal-btn-close">hide me</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a viable alternative.