# semantic-ui modal size keeps extending to the height of a page

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, semantic-ui

I'm trying to implement a basic modal, but its size is kept being extended to height of a page.

Trigger code:

```
$('.ui.modal.apply-modal').modal('show');
```

Modal Code:

```
<div class="ui modal apply-modal">
<i class="close icon"></i>
<div class="header">
  Modal Title
</div>
<div class="content">
  facebook
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <div class="ui button">Cancel</div>
  <div class="ui button">OK</div>
</div>
```

[image: Modal Window]

Comment: It seems like you cannot set the modal size with the jQuery plugin options so use CSS instead, when modal is open right click on it and hit "Inspect Element", check the CSS and modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out that [Bootstrap](https://atmospherejs.com/twbs/bootstrap) package is conflicting with [Semantic-UI](https://atmospherejs.com/semantic/ui) package I use.

Simply by doing:

```
meteor remove twbs:bootstrap
```

Things got resolved. Granted, not an ideal solution, but I should not be using both frameworks at the same time anyways.

[image]

Well, after about two hours of debugging....

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I could have never figured this out myself!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. My solution was modify the CSS of the modal component from Semantic UI in this way:

```
 .modal { position: relative;} or #myModal { position: relative;}

<div id="myModal" class="ui small modal"></div>
```

It works for me, I hope to help you. I agree with Michael Khait, this issue maybe occurs for any conflict between Boostrap and Semantic UI

Answer (score 1):

It is because Semantic and bootstrap Modal CSS rules are conflicting with each other
So what You can do is simply assign following CSS Rules to your main Div or wrapper class

```
top: auto;
bottom: auto;
right: auto;
left: auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on `op` answer, if you don't want to remove `Bootstrap` by any reason you can use this rule to fix the issue, just add a custom `class` to your semantic modal then `unset` all positions:

```
.Semantic-Modal {
    top: unset!important;
    right: unset!important;
    bottom: unset!important;
    left: unset!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also decide to override the css, that is the `modal` class

```css
.modal{
        bottom: auto!important;
        left: auto!important;
        right: auto!important;
        top: auto!important;
    }
```

This one worked perfectly for me