# Semantic UI Modal Height too long

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I am using semantic UI to create a webpage (No React, NPM or anything fancy, just plain HTML/CSS). I am trying to add modal to my page but it behaves very strange as the modal height is too long. I don't have any other framework like Bootstrap included in my code.

**How it behaves:**

[image: Image for my code]

**How it is supposed to behave:**

[image: Standard Image]

**Semantic UI Version:** 2.4.2

**Is Semantic UI Installed correctly?** Yes, other components work.

### My Code

#### HTML:

```
<div id="myModal" class="ui basic modal">
        <div class="ui icon header">
            <i class="archive icon"></i>
            Archive Old Messages
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Your inbox is getting full, would you like us to enable automatic archiving of old messages?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <div class="ui red basic cancel inverted button">
                <i class="remove icon"></i>
                No
            </div>
            <div class="ui green ok inverted button">
                <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
                Yes
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

#### JS:

```
$('.ui.basic.modal')
  .modal('show')
;
```

### What I tried till now:

1. `#myModal { position: relative;}` and then adding id to my modal, as explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40774996/10934182
2. `body{ max-height: 100vh; }` as explained here: [semantic-ui modal stretching window height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425389/semantic-ui-modal-stretching-window-height)
3. Code explained in this Fiddle (Not my fiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/MrLogical/2hda8e18/

*Thanks!!*

Comment: which class make it so long?

Comment: @GilangRizkie How would I know?

Comment: inspect element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JSfiddle I noticed your div inside of `.modal-content` has `min-height: 1000px`. I removed this and the modal is normal height now.

Comment: This is not my fiddle. It's someone else's. I just referenced it. I said that I tried that fiddle but it doesn't work. I don't have something like `min-height: 1000px` in my code.

Comment: Sorry, it said code was explained in the fiddle.
Have you tried inspecting the elements of the modal in the dev tools? It seems like something has a really tall height on there or tall min-height somewhere.

Comment: Well, I tried to inspect it and I found nothing referring to the height of the modal. I don't know what's causing the problem.

Comment: Maybe the class `.content` is being used on your site somewhere else and it's set to a certain height?

Comment: If not, we might need to see the CSS

Comment: Woohoo awesome! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the problem with the height of the modal. This is because of the version of 'semantic-ui-css' latest version. You can solve this issue by installing the 2.2.14 version of the semantic-ui-css
*

> npm install semantic-ui-css@2.2.14

*
It did for me and many other. So hope it'll work for you also